# Who was the first human to survive a vertical launched rocket flight?

Tags: spaceflight

In 1961 Yuri Gagarin flew a rocket and survived, parachuting safely back to earth.
According to Wikipedia, [Lothar Sieber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lothar_Sieber), a German pilot, tested a rocket in 1945 but died in the first test flight.

So the question is who is the first man to have survived a manned vertical rocket launch? This is presumably without reaching space and landing the rocket via controlled flight, or a parachute or other means.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it appears that Lothar Sieber was the first man to vertically launch in a rocket, the [Bachem Ba 349](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachem_Ba_349) Mark 23 prototype anti-bomber craft he was test-piloting for the Luftwaffe on March 1, 1945. Unfortunately for him, later phases of its test flight did not go well, and he ended up dying in the crash.

There were three recorded *successful* manned test flights after that, but I can't find any reference to the names of those pilots. Presumably the first one of those would be the guy fitting your critera. It seems likely that information wasn't recorded (perhaps for security reasons at the time). However, its also possible there might be claimants after the war ended.

After the test flights, they ordered a production run, and were all set to launch the first *operational* flights on Hitler's birthday when the US army overran the operational launch site near Stuttgart. So it looks like it was a few years where those three test pilots (assuming they survived their other Luftwaffe duties) were the only living humans to have performed this feat.

The only online source I've found with good detailed information about the later stages of the project (after that fatal test flight) referenced the book [Projekt Natter, Last of the Wonder Weapons](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2274176.Projekt_Natter), by Brett Gooden

Comment: Interestingly, there are multiple online sources that report that the project was cancelled due to the crash, and multiple others that include the detail about the 3 later successful flights, and some other details.

Comment: Do any giive sources for "manned flight after crash"? Most I read were retelling the tale that only a few more *unmanned* flights took place.

Comment: @LangLangC - No, they don't, so IMHO skepticism for both aftermath tales wouldn't be entirely unjustified at this point. I'm inclined to lean towards the "three more flights" story based on the fact that one version of it (on WP) goes into more detail about the production numbers that were ordered, and what happened them all, and what couldn't be found, which sounds much duller and less tidy of a story to have made up than simply "it got cancelled". But it could use better documentation.

Comment: @T.E.D. [This video](https://youtu.be/r9iTDssif7g?t=1036) claims [at 17:15] that the further test flights were scheduled for Hitler's birthday, but the site was over-run by allied forces before they could take place.  The author (if that's the correct term?) doesn't offer sources, but does have a Discord site, so I guess we could ask him?

Comment: @sempaiscuba - According to [this bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachem_Ba_349#Operation_Krokus_launch_pads_at_Hasenholz_wood) at the end of the WP page those were not test flights, but rather the first **operational flights** that were scheduled on Hitler's birthday, but overrun by US troops. This much they *do* have a reference for: "Gooden, Brett A. Projekt Natter, Last of the Wonder Weapons". Added to answer.

Comment: @T.E.D. Yeah, I saw that, but I'm struggling with the timeline. Sieber's crash was about 7 weeks before Hitler's birthday. In that time they had to identify the cause of the crash (& write the report), fix any issues, conduct 3 test flights, then train the operational pilots? I haven't read the book (and I can't find an online copy), but I'd guess the three claimed '_successful manned test flights_' and the three planned operational flights with '_manned and fully armed A1 Krokus_' aircraft are talking about the same thing.

Comment: @sempaiscuba - It seems a possibility the writers were confused. However, I think the operational training *could* have been going on in parallel with the test flights, and turn-around times measured in weeks when there was intense wartime pressure going on doesn't seem utterly impossible.

Comment: @T.E.D. Impossible? No.  But it does seem somewhat unlikely. Can't you just imagine what might have happened if it all went wrong?  [<cut to Führerbunker > _Hitler_: "And what did you get me for my birthday, Heinrich?" _Himmler_: "Well, Adolph, I killed three of our top pilots!  L'Chaim!"]

Comment: @sempaiscuba train operational pilots? Don't be daft. We're talking the emergency fighter program here, these craft were intended for raw recruits to fly (and get killed in, all of them were a handful to put it mildly, and would have caused a very high rate of accidents had HJ and VS recruits been put in them).

Comment: @jwenting Sieber was no raw recruit. Nor would the pilots for any subsequent test flights have been.  Pilots were less of an issue than the aircraft itself - it's why the rocket motor was designed to be recoverable.  By that point, they simply didn't have resources to waste on the aircraft (it also used the same fuel as the ME163, for example).  The _first_ operational pilots would have been properly trained to make sure the thing actually worked from a vertical launch.  After that, yes you're right, they didn't have enough skilled pilots, and the losses would have been unsupportable.

Comment: @sempaiscuba - Sounds like you're arguing *for* the WP narrative here. Risking a public launch on Hitler's birthday makes far more sense if they'd already made 3 successful manned launches.

Comment: @T.E.D. Actually, given the restricted timescale, I suspect the vertical launch(es) on 20 April would probably have been the test flights, and only made public if successful.  Of course that doesn't preclude the possibility of manned air-drop tests in the interval.  However, since I don't have access to hard evidence, it can only be a suspicion (and a natural distrust of sites that don't cite sources for their claims!).

Comment: @sempaiscuba I didn't say Sieber was a recruit, but the eventual pilots of the production versions would be. That was the entire point of the emergency fighter program.

Answer (score 2):

Define "rocket flight". The Natter wasn't technically a rocket, it was a rocket powered aircraft.

After the vertical boost phase, it was controlled using aerodynamic flight surfaces (or that was the plan).

According to a more strict definition the honour would go to either Yuri Gagarin or Alan Shepard (as Gagarin didn't land inside his craft).